# TypeScript - can you type check for an interface extending from a certain type without a type guard?

Tags: typescript, interface, extends

I have a custom router component: -

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { ReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client'

export interface BaseCurrentUserType {
    id: string
}

interface Props {
    currentUserReactiveVar: ReactiveVar<BaseCurrentUserType | null>
    [...otherProps]
}
const CustomRoutes = (props: Props): ReactElement => (
    [...]
)
```

So it employs an exportable interface which I want other components to be able to use. The entire point of this is to make sure that, by enforcing BaseCurrentUserType as the type, it means I can always expect there to be an id property present in the CurrentUser object.

So I then import from my CustomRoutes, extend from the BaseCurrentUserType and try to pass that: -

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import CustomRoutes, { BaseCurrentUserType } from './CustomRoutes'
import { makeVar } from '@apollo/client'

export interface CurrentUser extends BaseCurrentUserType {
    username: string
}

export const currentUser = makeVar<CurrentUser | null>(null)

const Index = (): ReactElement => (
    <CustomRoutes
        currentUserReactiveVar={currentUser}
        ...otherProps
    />
)
```

That is where the issue arises - TypeScript no longer sees the type as BaseCurrentUserType as it has been extended to CurrentUser. Is there any way to code this so TS will accept an interface/object that is an extension of BaseCurrentUserType? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was very simple: -

```
export const currentUser = makeVar<BaseCurrentUserType | null>(null)

export interface CurrentUser extends BaseCurrentUserType {
    username: string
}
```

I just needed to pass the type as BaseCurrentUserType!